# Is there a list of all known non-production/q parts anywhere?

Tags: part-database

Pretty self explanatory, I’ve tried the bricklink color catalogue but that seems to only show parts that are currently being sold, am I missing something?

Comment: What do you mean by "non-production/q" ? The bricklink catalogue contains both parts that are currently in production and parts that aren't.

Comment: In referring to parts never produced commercially (ie a marbled 2 x 4) Also included are mold and color combinations that have never been in sets. (ie a 2 x 2 tile in olive green) And I’m looking for a list of known parts, not just whats currently for sale.

Comment: Bricklink list all parts known to them, whether any is for sale currently. I have bought parts in colours not in any sets on bricklink. But I'm not sure they list everything, in part because it's hard to find out what "everything" is.

Comment: Where could I find that list?

Comment: If you go to the color info tab for a given part - eg. [Plate, Round 1 x 1](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=4073#T=C), you'll find 4 lists of colors for this part - each with their own meaning (ref. [What is the meaning of the available color lists in Bricklink searches?](https://bricks.stackexchange.com/questions/13458/what-is-the-meaning-of-the-available-color-lists-in-bricklink-searches) for details). For your use, "known colors" == "production parts" and the additional colors in "lots for sale" might be "non-production parts" (or just errors by the seller).

Comment: I am aware of that, however I’m looking for a list of _all_ known non-production parts, not just those currently for sale